# Featured Links/Blogroll (irrelevant links) in a blog is good or bad for SEO?

Tags: seo, links, backlinks, blogroll

While I’m checking my websites’ back links using backlink watch tool I saw so many backlinks are from Blogspots where my links are placed under the category featured Links.

The main problem is my web site is related to boxing but that blog is related to software and viruses. I don’t know whether this backlinks are good or bad in SEO point of view. If I remove those links my backlink will reduce. Will my web sites PR decreases if I remove those backlinks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worst case for your boxing site is that these links are irrelevant. Otherwise it would be too easy to hurt competitors by placing links on arbitary pages.

I would leave the links where they are now. Yes, removing them could decrease PR.

Start working now on relevant links to your site.

Comment: Thank you John.. From now itself i try to build quality links for my website..

Comment: Relevancy trumps every other metric possible. If the site has irrelevant / spammy backlinks pointing to their site, then they should remove them. A site with 1 backlinks can out-perform a site with 100,000 backlinks if the backlinks is of significant relevancy and onsite is well structured / providing great value.